# Using a bar of soap on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cleaning

I have heard plenty of times that one shouldn't use bar soap on Shabbat. What are the sources for this Pesak and why is this so?

[My LOR](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=932&txtSearch=soap%20bar) says Yesh Al Mi Lismoch but I would like to see a nice treatment of the Sugya.

Comment: IIRC there's a responsum permitting this in Yabia Omer.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think so too ;D

Comment: HachamGabriel You heard he broke his arm writing that teshuva? Rav Ovadia found a svara that helped him in a book by the Chayei Adam and got so excited he ran back to write it in the teshuva, but forgot he was at the top of a ladder on a bookshelf, so he fell and broke his arm.

Comment: @DoubleAA no way?! En Bet Midrash Belo Hidush.

Comment: The craziest part of the story is he had to look something up in a book!

Comment: @DoubleAA never thought about that...that's hilarious!

Comment: יחוה דעת חלק ב סימן נ

Comment: Related (liquid soap): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48916/5323

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Chicago Community Kollel Parsha Encounters Oct 23, 2009](http://www.cckollel.org/parsha_encounters/5770/noach_70.pdf) discusses the issues with bar soap.

> The Rama (326:10) writes that it is forbidden to wash one's hands with
>   soap on Shabbos. Three reasons are given for this prohibition. The
>   Rama explains that using soap on Shabbos causes it to turn into
>   liquid, which is a violation of Nolad (creating a new entity).
>
> This reason is not accepted by the Magen Avraham (brought in Mishna
>   Berura 326:30). He argues that the main purpose of soap is not to
>   serve as a liquid, and therefore, the prohibition of Nolad is not
>   relevant to soap.
>
> A second reason for the prohibition, mentioned by the Mishna Berura
>   ibid., is that using soap is in violation of Mimarayach (smearing).
>   Many Poskim argue that this reason only applies to soap used in
>   previous generations, which was rough and needed to be smoothed. This
>   would not apply to bar soap used in modern times, which is quiet
>   smooth. (Some brands of bar soap have pointy edges; perhaps smoothing
>   those edges is in violation of Mimarayach. Additionally, if a bar of
>   soap remains in water for some time, it can become pasty and soft. If
>   one wipes off the soft part in order to smooth out the bar, he may
>   have violated the prohibition of Mimarayach.)
>
> A third reason quoted by the Mishna Berura, is that soap may be so
>   abrasive that it will pull out hair on Shabbos. This reason, too, does
>   not apply to modern soap.
>
> In conclusion, there is a universal custom to avoid using bar soap on
>   Shabbos. Although the rationale behind this custom may be unclear, we
>   dare not tamper with this custom (Mishna Berura 326:30, Aruch Hashulchan 326:11,
>   Shmiras Shabbos Khilchasa 14:16, Ben Ish Chai II Yisro 15, Kitzur
>   Hilchos Shabbos 32:4). However in extenuating circumstances one may
>   wash his hands using bar soap. It is preferable, however, to use the
>   soap under running water (Shmiras Shabbos Khilchasa 40:11).

Comment: Yeyasher Kochacha on making good on [your surname](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/104/halacha?userid=200)!