# Chalking pool cues on shabbat/yom-tov

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, games-toys

May one chalk a pool cue on shabbat and yom tov? If not, why?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30673 doesn't *seem* relevant.

Answer (score 4):

According to Rav Moshe Feinstein  re:makeup on shabbos (where he asserts that Tochen-grinding would apply to face powders that are caked) tochen too would be a problem.

Comment: Hello mmt and welcome to mi.yodeya! Can you provide a source for Rav Moshe's _p'sak_ in this regard and a few words of explanation on how it applies to this case?

Comment: Not a written Teshuvah,however it is reported by many of his students. The Star-K, in their Shabbos Cosmetic article (by Rav Heber) quotes it, as does Rabbi Jachter in Grey Matter. Perhaps it is in a more recently published teshuvah, but it is known in the olam ha'psak.

Answer (score 0):

I've always heard that it's forbidden to chalk a pool cue, as it is being used for marking something. Furthermore, I've always heard that chalk is muktzah, so this is another reason against.

source: אבי מורי

Comment: Marking is not a melacha, the actual prohibition is against writing 2 letters and the Rabbis extend this to cases that may lead to 2 letters, however, marking as an unintended consequence is permitted. Muktzah is something that has no permitted use on shabbat/yom-tov, chalk (assuming it can be used) would not be muktzah.

Comment: FWIW you probably mean אבי מרי (my father and my master)

Comment: @DoubleAA _mori_ means "my teacher", no? Seems more relevant when citing a source than "my master". `:-P`

Comment: @msh210 Yes, but he probably meant to be using the traditional term of respect for his father, not some made up phrase which sounds similar.

Comment: @DoubleAA in benching we say אבי מורי.

Comment: @Scimonster I don't know who "we" is, but if some do they are again not following the traditional formulation. Everyone is entitled to make up whatever formulation they want so long as the parent doesn't disagree.

Comment: @DoubleAA I checked a few benchers (nusach Ashkenaz), and they all say אבי מורי. Among them: ArtScroll, Feldheim, NCSY, Nevarech.

Comment: @Scimonster Sad that they have all veered from tradition.  But waddya you gonna do, right?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I meant "my teacher", rather than "my master".

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Why did you choose to use a non-traditional formulation of respect which so closely sounds like a traditional one?

Comment: My father (sh"y) would likely dislike it were I to use master versus teacher. Furthermore, the resemblance was intentional, and in most of the benchers I've seen, as Scimonster points out, they use מורי instead of מרי. This is the formulation I grew up with.

Comment: If your father prefers it, then go ahead I guess. The [Gemara](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=31b&format=pdf) though is clear that you should source your father as אבא מרי which Rashi translates as אבי ואדוני.